# Issue with my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope this question is okay to ask, basically i'm trying to update some customer details but when i click continue i get an error message saying there is an error with my SQL but i cannot see the issue with the SQL if anyone knows and can let me know thank you very much because i can't see my issue ( i will add im new to SQL so it may be something simple sorry!)

If it makes a difference my database is on phpmyadmin

This is the error message:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE customer_id = '579'' at line 1
>   Error No: 1064
>   UPDATE customer SET firstname = 'blank', lastname = 'blank', email = 'blank', telephone = 'blank', fax = '', WHERE customer_id = '579'

(I've changed the information to blank because it was real information)

and this is my code

```
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET firstname = 
        '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . 
        $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db-
        >escape($data['email']) . "', telephone = '" . $this->db-
        >escape($data['telephone']) . "', fax = '" . $this->db-
        >escape($data['fax']) . "', WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this-
        >customer->getId() . "'");
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's a comma before `where`, that's not OK.  `fax = '', WHERE`

Comment: Why are you querying directly? Taking a stab in the dark, you'll probably find that you can do `$this->db->update('customer', $data, 'customer_id = '.$this->customer->getId());` or something like it.

Comment: Just removed that comma and that fixed everything thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As andomar said in his comment you have to delete the comma before WHERE...

Answer (score 1):

The comma before the WHERE clause indicates to MySql to expect more fields to update.  If you delete the comma it should work depending on the layout of your database.

Also, it shouldn't matter, but I'm quite certain you don't need to cast the ID to an int.